# Why In-App purchase sandbox always ask "Verification Required"?

Tags: iphone, app-store, in-app-purchase, sandbox

I have signed out from the store in device settings.
I entered user credentials only in my App.
I have set up a brand new (actually around 4 times) test user.

Why this message keep poppin' up?

Is it something connected to iOS 5, automatic app sync, or iCloud?

Comment: Idiotism, just keep asking me to verify my payement info, but the label [Environment: Sandbox] is present. Please help me out here.

Comment: Geri, did you get the solution for this? I'm having exactly the same problem.

Comment: Do test user with Canadian Store.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I had exactly same problem with sandbox in-app purchases, in built-in model (no receipt verification), app received valid products, now i called addPayment, everything alright. But now "Verification required" appeared and payment was canceled.

After hours of pain I discovered, my problem was in test account.. i created test account for Czech Republic iTunes store... and that was the reason of fail. Dumb.
I tried to create Canadian test user and it suddenly worked! "Verification required" will no longer appeared.

Comment: and do you usually access Czech appstore, when not in sandbox mode?

Comment: Switching to Canadian appstore seems to have helped. No idea why, but I think that's the solution :) thanks

Comment: For us, until few days back, selecting Japan store for a test user had been OK, but now a test user with US store works, not Japan Store.

Comment: Indeed, that was the issue. For some strange reason, iTunes sandbox user accounts set up for AppStores other than US stopped working for us in the app, while test user accounts bound to the US AppStore work fine.

Comment: Man you saved my life after days and days of failing to test.

Comment: Works for me too, but I'm gonna ask Apple to fix this.

Comment: The same solution has helped here. It doesn't seem to work with UK accounts only by registering US accounts for testing.

Answer (score 11):

I've dealing with this problem for about one week, trying to use accounts in US/Canada without any success. Finally I found this post and it works:
http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/63008-in-app-purchase-test-account-verification-required-cant-get-passed.html
You need a test account that NEVER has a credit card attached to it, NEVER is logged into itunes store or app store via device, and if you do login to itunes or agree to any app store stuff it voids the test account and will never work again.

So, To test your In App Purchase app, you need to use a new account that does not have a credit card. logout of the store, and only use your new account inside the app you are testing.

Update: After a long time system maintenance of iTunes in Sept 2013, only test accounts in US can make test purchases.

Comment: This was exactly my issue. To make it more clear, set up the account on iTunes Connect, sign out on your device of any account. Go through your In App Purchase and sign in directly using your app. Do not agree to any contract or legal agreement. Should work after that.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked for me. Just create, then use directly from the app. Before, I was breaking the accounts by doing things like signing in from Settings -> Store and/or entering credit card information.

Answer (score 3):

I have struggled with this myself, i finally found a workaround that worked for me...

1. On the device Log out of iTunes account in settings (also hard close settings and iTunes if you have them open as a precaution)
2. Delete app
3. Create a new test user at “itunesconnect.apple.com” – selecting the United States as your store
4. Reinstall app
5. Try to make a purchase in the app
6. Enter you new test user account details
7. If a pop up states that it needs to swap stores, immediately press home. DO NOT press OK.
8. Relaunch the app, and try again. It should now work as expected.

Hope this works...

Answer (score 2):

In addition of the above answers, note the below points also :-

1) Uninstall your app from the device.

2) Create a new test account on iTunes Connect and verify its email address. Never add any payment information for this test account, not online, not on iTunes, not on your device. Doing so might invalidate your test account (and trigger the "verify payment info" vicious cycle.) Also never use this test account out of the Sandbox.

3) Log-out from the App Store on your device. DO NOT log back in the App Store via Settings > iTunes & App Stores on your device. You will be asked your login credentials from your app later (see points 5-6)

4) Re-install your app.

5) Attempt an in-app purchase. You should now be prompted to enter both your username and password (as you logged out from the App Store)

6) Type in your username and password: you should not see the dreadful "Verification Required: before you can make purchases, you must verify your payment info" message and the purchase should be successful.

Answer (score 1):

Even in sandbox, you need to complete the buy verifying the receipt to the server.
It corresponds to steps 6-7-8 of built-in model and 11-12-13 of the server model.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/APIOverview/OverviewoftheStoreKitAPI.html

All you need to do is:

Retrieve the receipt data from the transaction’s transactionReceipt property and encode it using base64 encoding.create a json like this:

```
{
    "receipt-data" : "(receipt in base 64 encoding)"
}
```

Make a post to verification URL for production:

https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

For sandbox :

https://sandbox.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt

The response is like this:

```
{
    "status" : 0,
    "receipt" : { ... }
}
```

If the value of the status key is `0`, this is a valid receipt.
If the value is anything other than `0`, this receipt is invalid.

For further information look the guide:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/VerifyingStoreReceipts/VerifyingStoreReceipts.html

Comment: This seems to be related to the verification of receipts; while my problem is on the side of Appstore asking me to verify my payment information when I perform a purchase and log in with my Test User account. It should just pass the transaction as successful instead. I haven't seen this behavior some time ago, when I last tested a purchase - however in the meantime iOS 5 rolled out and I'm not sure what to blame here.

Comment: Im getting this kind of dialog box after entering my TEST id and password: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3943878/sandbox_dialog.png

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**

Insert this temporary code somewhere in your project:

```
for transaction: AnyObject in SKPaymentQueue.default().transactions {
    guard let currentTransaction: SKPaymentTransaction = transaction as? SKPaymentTransaction else {return}
    SKPaymentQueue.default().finishTransaction(transaction as! SKPaymentTransaction)
}
```

This clears out the payment queue.  Make sure to run it much later than viewDidLoad if you can.  I made mine triggered by a button. Ran it a couple times, then removed the code.  No more annoying verification pop-ups.

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue after iOS5 got released.

Earlier I used to create test accounts with dummy email addresses and it used to work well for me, but post iOS5, it started showing verification required for test accounts.

Thus I ended up using actual email addresses for the test accounts and verified when asked for, which seemed to do the trick for me.

Comment: I'm using real addresses, and I have tried to Verifiy the accounts (and tried to not as well), but it keeps asking for Verify, and purchase has not made.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem after spending several hours i figured out that **county/region of your itunes connect test account and your device/simulator must be same**.

Please verify it as it solved my problem

Comment: Where did you change the country/region of the device?  I have Settings > General > International already on same country as test account, and still have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Register a fresh test user for the USA. You can put any email address.

Log out under settings. 
Delete the app. 
start it again via xCode
login with your new user within the app.

It may say that you are not located in the USA and it opens the browser, Close the browser and start it again.

It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

*If you are having such problem for 4th IAP item to buy.*

It looks, each test account does not work for purchasing more than 3 items of an application. You may create a new test account from **itunesconnect.apple.com->Manage Users->Test User** to test your 4th IAP item.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a **canadian test user** solve this issue.