# In-App purchases outside of US store

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I'm implementing In-App purchases and while testing with a sandbox account I get this message:

> **Compte non utilisable dans ce pays**
>
> Votre compte ne peut pas etre utilise dans le Store francais. Vous
>   devez passer au Store americain pour pouvoir faire des achats.

Approximate translation:

> **Account not usable in this country**
>
> Your account cannot be used in the French Store. You must go to the
>   US Store to make purchases.

Why is this message appearing? Is there any other setting required to allow In-App purchases with accounts which uses different store than US?

Answer (score 0):

You can select the country when you create a new sandbox user.

Comment: Yes, I know this. But why it asks me to switch to the US store? Seems like it still says to the old store when signing in to another account, but I'm not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

As complement the @bjilham answer.

I'm in LatinAmerica and always show this message in SandBox but this don't carry any problem. Just let them to go AppStore and automatically change the store and then you can retry connect inside your App to buy in-app.

I believe Apple just have an environment for US store because is just for test.

Maybe help this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044217/why-in-app-purchase-sandbox-always-ask-verification-required)