# iOS In app purchase sandbox user asking for verification

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, apple-id

I created a test user for the irish store

Signed out of my personal account

Launched the application and tried to make the purchase

I get the "Apple ID Verification" prompt

Asks me to set a new password

Please help

Comment: I have the same issue. For some reason sandbox users are no longer working as before. Have you too tried everything from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8044217/why-in-app-purchase-sandbox-always-ask-verification-required?rq=1

Comment: The only thing you could try is to make an internal Test Flight version and then test with your actual Apple ID. I didn't have time to try do that yet.

Comment: I will try that, thank you

Comment: Same issue and I have tried everything recommended by apple. I even requested support from them and so far silence from their end.

Comment: Exactly the same here. I suppose, it's a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue (Australian App Store) and today things seem to have gone back to normal, but the behaviour is slightly different from before.

This has now worked for me:
- Created a new Sandbox user on iTunes Connect.
- Followed the link in the email sent to verify the email address.
- In the app, when interacting with StoreKit, the app will then ask for the App Store credentials. Enter the username and password.
- The "Apple ID Verification" alert will pop up. Tap "Settings".
- Change the password as instructed.
- In the app, repeat the operation that interacts with StoreKit. This should now work correctly.

Comment: Can confirm that it is working again. It was probably an issue on the Apple side.

Answer (score 0):

Now is working fine...after friday 13 jan the same process works as expected. It's enough to verify the email and the sandbox allows you to try IAP! Should be only an Apple bug on their servers.

Answer (score -1):

You need to setup Test users in iTunes Connect portal which you can use to test In App purchase functionality with Sandbox environment. You can't test in-app purchase functionality in sandbox environment using actual Apple account.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: Your answer seems obsolete: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/testing_in-app_purchase_transactions